# Conjectured Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I noticed that for positive integers $(a,b,c)$, it happens that $ab+bc+ca$ is always greater than $abc+1$. Is this true, and if it is, how would I prove it?

Comment: take $a=b=c=10$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume that $a\ge b\ge c.$Then consider $$ab+bc+ca>abc+1\tag 1.$$ Note that $$3a^2\ge ab+bc+ca\tag 2$$ and $$abc+1\ge c^3+1>c^3\tag 3$$  by $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ we have $3a^2>c^3.$
But there are infinitely many integers simultaniously satisfying the conditions $$a\ge c,\,\, c^3\ge 3a^2.$$

For example:
$$(a,b,c)\in\{ (9,8,7), (10,9,8), (11,10,9) \}.$$
Hence your conjected inequality does not hold for large class of integers.

Comment: This show that there are integers violate your inequality other than $a=b=c\ge 3.$

Answer (score 2):

What about $a=b=c=5$? $ $     $  $   $   $  $    $

Answer (score 2):

If $a=b=c$, then your conjecture become $a^3+1<3a^2\implies a=1,2$. All other positive integers do not satisfy the inequality. Hence we have an infinite set of points where your conjecture is false.